# wso2 cep - how to programmatically change a query

Tags: wso2, wso2-cep

I have a query to start off with - but want to add more conditions as the business case is updated. Is there a way to programmatically update the running query without having to use the UI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do above task.

1) Copy execution plan (which contains siddhi queries) directly to deployment directory. (/repository/deployment/server/executionplans )

2) Deploy the execution plan through admin services.

But, please not if you change the query in runtime, it make affect the current process where data which is in the window or memory will get lost.

Thanks,
Mohan